Can I return to Canada from a visa-exempt country, as a Canadian PR without a card?
I am a permanent resident of Canada and a citizen of New Zealand (so I have a New Zealand passport). I live in Canada, and I have a vacation to New Zealand coming up.
My PR card expired, and although I have applied for a replacement, the Canada Post strike may prevent it from arriving before I leave.
I am aware I can apply for a PR Travel Document once I get to New Zealand (or maybe online before I leave), but I am not confident that it will arrive in time either.
Given that New Zealand is a visa-exempt country, could I simply board my return flight and show the Canadian border officer my expired card, passport, Canadian drivers' licence, etc?
Additionally, will I need an eTA to execute this plan? Can I still get one as a PR?

The problem is usually that far before you will see a border officer you will need to convince the airline to let you board. Without your PR card they will probably require an ETA, but I have no idea if you can get one as a PR…

Do you have the expired card?

@DJClayworth yes, I have the expired card.

I am a US citizen and have flown from the US to Canada presenting my US passport to get on the plane and presenting my expired PR card at border control in Canada. The airline didn't seem to have any problems letting me board. The Canadian border officers gave me a hard time but let me enter.  (Oops, I didn't see the "except a US passport holder" proviso in the answer below ...)

@BenBolker A US citizen wouldn't need an ETA.

You have a right to enter Canada as soon as you satisfy the border officer that you have the permanent resident status, which nowadays can be easily verified against electronic records (assuming you acquired the PR status in the past 20 years).
However, to board an international flight to Canada as a national from a visa-exempt country (except a U.S. passport holder), you must either prove your PR status with a PR card or travel document, or have an electronic travel authorization (eTA). The eTA requirement is strict and the airlines can verify the eTA status with the Canadian authorities: without a valid eTA, the airlines will (are supposed to) receive a do-not-board message, unless you present a recognized PR document.
An eTA cannot be granted to permanent residents (unless you lie in the form, which may be considered as misrepresentation and can have serious consequences, although in practice it may be rare to prosecute). The special authorization available to certain Canadian citizens does not extend to permanent residents.
The situation is different (in practice, at least in recent times) for permanent residents from a visa-required country who have an apparently valid visa (though technically invalidated by their PR status), who may be allowed to board based on the temporary resident visa, though this (technically not allowed) workaround may become impossible due to additional advanced passenger information verifications.

You can, however, fly to the United States with a valid U.S. visa or ESTA (assuming you are eligible for the American visa waiver program) and exercise your right to enter Canada at a land border after you are admitted to the United States. That is the usual solution recommended for people who want to do it "correctly", though at additional costs.

In emergency/humanitarian situations, you can ask for expedited processing of your PR travel document with the webform or telephone the concerned consular section directly.

Thank you, I may end up booking a refundable ticket to the USA in case my documents don't arrive in time. Do you happen to know if I would be able to transit through Canada on my way to the US for this case?

@Blorgbeard Air transit through Canada requires an eTA so you cannot book an itinerary through Canada; otherwise you would be able to simply forfeit the subsequent leg once you are on Canadian land (this trick for example only works if you qualify for the TWOV/CTP in case you have a Chinese/Taiwanese/Philippine/Indonesian/Thai passport).

Do you know why US passport holders have special status in this situation?

@BenBolker US citizens and permanent residents do not require an eTA to arrive in Canada by air. The exception is a political decision that's influenced by practical considerations (given the number of Canadians and Americans going to the other country). Canadians going to the U.S. are also exempt from ESTA and most non-immigrant visas.
